# Animation programmatically on Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm doing an app and I plan to make some animations.
I want to create rectangles in the upper part of the screen, and they will go to the bottom of the screen.
I would like to ask you what would you recommend for me how to make this animation?
I want to make it programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please search before using SO.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html) on the android-developers blog. It shows how to do many animations using the APIs introduced in HoneyComb. You can also use them in older versions of android using the [NineOldAndroid](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library.